# Why does this loop reverses a String in Java

Tags: java, string, loops

I'm trying to remove whitespaces in a given string, and, while I've achieved this, the returned String appears reversed. Can anyone please explain why?

```
public String removeSpaces(String cadena) {
    String noSpace="";
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        if (cadena.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            noSpace=noSpace;
        }else{
            noSpace=cadena.charAt(i)+noSpace;
        }
    }
    return noSpace;
}
```

Comment: `noSpace=cadena.charAt(i)+noSpace;` => `noSpace=noSpace + cadena.charAt(i);` - Also you could just do `cadena = cadena.replace(" ","");`

Comment: Did you try to figure it out yourself with a small example?

Comment: Because you add the character to the beginning of the string? Also, why bother with the no-op?

Comment: I see. If I change the order it returns de String in the proper order. Still I don't understand why does it reverses it :/

Thanks anyway ;) And yes, I've tried a few things that didn't work. Bear in mind, I'm in my first month in Java and I usually ask our teacher but he's been sick for a couple of days and this is part of a big assignment and didn't have anything more than Google to figure it out.

Comment: @nakkeru What is there to understand? Play computer and write down what's happening. If your string is `ABC` you're building the output string like this: `"A" + ""`, `"B" + "A"`, `"C" + "BA"`. Easy enough. If you add the character at the *end* of your output string it's this: `"" + "A"`, `"A" + "B"`, `"AB" + "C"`

Answer (score 1):

To remove whitespace, you could have done something like the following:

`str.replaceAll("\\s+","")`

Comment: Well, we aren't supposed to know how to use methods so we are forced to do it in a more "manual" way, sort to speak.

But thanks ;)

Comment: Don't forget that you can always look at Java source code to see how the methods are implemented under the hood. They can be used as a learning tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this kind of method just change it slightly:

```
public String removeSpaces(String cadena) {
String noSpace="";
for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
    if (cadena.charAt(i) != ' ') {
        noSpace+=cadena.charAt(i);
    }
}
return noSpace;
}
```